# How to deploy tools.jar into Nexus using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, tools.jar

From the same directory I tried to deploy 
spark-assembly-1.6.2.2.5.0.0-1245-hadoop2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar
and 
tools.jar 
(the later being a dependency of the first)
Despite launching the same commands:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=./spark-assembly-1.6.2.2.5.0.0-1245-hadoop2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar -DgroupId="spark.yarn.jar" -DartifactId="spark-assembly-1.6.2.2.5.0.0-1245-hadoop2.7.3.2.5.0.0" -Dversion="1245-SNAPSHOT" -Dpackaging="jar" -DrepositoryId="stmms-id" -Durl="http://nexus.some.dns.com:8090/repository/maven-snapshots"

mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=./tools.jar                                                      -DgroupId="jdk.tools"      -DartifactId="jdk.tools"                                             -Dversion="1.7.0_07"      -Dpackaging="jar" -DrepositoryId="stmms-id" -Durl="http://nexus.some.dns.com:8090/repository/maven-snapshots"
```

the first is successfull but the second fails:
I also tried maven-deploy-plugin but with no much success.

Comment: fails how? What is the error?

Comment: Share more information about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository `maven-snapshots` is a SNAPSHOT repository. You can only deploy SNAPSHOT versions to it.

So `-Dversion="1245-SNAPSHOT"` is ok, but `-Dversion="1.7.0_07"` is not.